# ListView <--> ImageList Will Not Sync

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, imagelist

I am using a ListView to load and display thumbnails for image files.  The "Name" or key that I'm using for each ListViewItem is the fully-qualified file name.

I have also created an ImageList which loads thumbnails of those files using the same key.  I've assigned this ImageList as the "SmallImageList" property of the ListView.

When I add and remove files, I add and remove them **by key** from both the ListView.Items and the ImageList.Images collections.

All of this works fine when loading many images.  However, when I try deleting a given key, the ListView control no longer displays the thumbnails properly.

Before and after deleting an item:

[image: Before]
[image: After]

When I analyze both collection arrays in memory during debugging, the keys line up perfectly.

Code used:

```
// Add the images from an array of paths
foreach (string xFile in files)
{
    thumbnails_imageList.Images.Add(xFile, images[xFile]);
    files_lst.Items.Add(xFile, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(xFile), xFile);
}

// Delete the selected key(s)
foreach (ListViewItem xItem in files_lst.SelectedItems)
{
    files_lst.Items.Remove(xItem);
    thumbnails_imageList.Images.RemoveByKey(xItem.Name);
}
```

Comment: I just finished converting my code to an index-based key and I'm getting the same exact issue.

Comment: For a solution that let's you delete the Images and still keep the Items point to the correct indices [see this post!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39916598/removing-listviewitem-with-image-from-listview/39920779#39920779)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what happens is clear, if you have a `ListViewItem` bound to image index `5` and you delete the image in position `4`, the 5 shifts down to 4 and the item keeps a reference to the `5` so does not show any image.

I think you should not remove the images from the `ImageList` when you remove the selected ListView items.

Comment: Won't this seriously leak memory?  If you never remove the images from the list, and you keep running the code over and over, you'd end up with a huge ImageList where most of the images are never used. How would you get around this?

Comment: For a solution that let's you delete the Images and still keep the Items point to the correct indices [see this post!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39916598/removing-listviewitem-with-image-from-listview/39920779#39920779)