# Removing ListViewItem with image from ListView

Tags: c#, listview, imagelist

I'm trying to dynamically change a `ListView` in my program. Every item has an `ImageKey` and I use a `SmallImageList` for them.

The problem is whenever I delete an item, the problem which was mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7908804/3025112) appears:

> Before and after deleting an item:
>
> [image: Before][image: After]
>
> Code used:
>
> ```
> // Add the images from an array of paths
> foreach (string xFile in files)
> {
>     thumbnails_imageList.Images.Add(xFile, images[xFile]);
>     files_lst.Items.Add(xFile, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(xFile), xFile);
> }
>
> // Delete the selected key(s)
> foreach (ListViewItem xItem in files_lst.SelectedItems)
> {
>     files_lst.Items.Remove(xItem);
>     thumbnails_imageList.Images.RemoveByKey(xItem.Name);
> }
> ```

The answer in the question (which recommends not to remove images from the `ImageList`) doesn't meet my requirements because I add items with the same `ImageKey` after removing, so, more than one `Image`s in `SmallImageList.Images` get the same `ImageKey`, therefore images become inconsistent. Also the answer ignores the obvious memory leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the removal of an  `Image` from the `ImageList` indeed causes the indices of the `Items` to move up. This means that internally the `Keys` are no longer used but are mapped to the indices when adding or setting and then no longer kept intact.

So to workaround you can either..:

- Keep all `Images` in the `ImageList` and live with the unnecessary `Images`. At 256x256pixels x 4 byte an `Image` can have only 256k, so the memory waste will not be so big. (Note that no GDI+ resources are wasted, since an `ImageList` doesn't create any handles for its `Images`.) But given enough adding/removing the growing size of the `ImageList` may become a problem..
- Or you can work around by storing and resetting the `ImageKeys`.

Here is an example:

```
private void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem xItem in listView1.SelectedItems)
    {
        // maybe insert the loop below here (*)
        listView1.Items.Remove(xItem);
        // only delete when no longer in use:
        string key = xItem.ImageKey;
        if (listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Count(x => x.ImageKey == key) == 0)
            imageList1.Images.RemoveByKey(key);

    }
    // after deletions, restore the ImageKeys
    // maybe add a check for Tag == null
    foreach (ListViewItem xItem in listView1.Items)
        xItem.ImageKey = xItem.Tag.ToString();

}
```

For this to work you need to store the correct key strings. I chose to do so in the `IListViewItem.Tag` property. You can do it when adding the `Items`  or right before the deleting:

```
foreach (ListViewItem xItem in listView1.Items)
        xItem.Tag = xItem.ImageKey;               // (*)
```

Comment: I don't use ImageIndex property. I already use ImageKey as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Whoops sorry. Misread the question. But why will you get duplicates then???

Comment: For example I remove an item with ImageKey = "a". Then at some point I add a new item with ImageKey = "a". But I add another image for "a" so they become duplicate.

Comment: Yes, but why not use unique names? Also: Before removing any Image from the ImageList you should test if any Item is still using it! Same for adding: Before adding an Image test to see if the Key is already there and then increment..

Comment: They are already unique within the list. The problem is when I use SmallImageList.RemoveByKey("a") while removing the item, the issue which was mentioned in the question appears. Another item loses its image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125193/discussion-between-farukdgn-and-taw).

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Reassigning ImageKeys solved the issue. They should've mentioned this in the documentation IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you try to modify list in the foreach loop. I would recommend first make a loop and remember the SelectedItems you want to delete in new list and then in the next loop delete them. This way you won't edit the list you are looping.